# Why need to extends Object?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I saw simple class which was look like:

```
class SomeClass extends Object{

  int a;
  int b;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Why this class was extended an Object class? As in documentation was written "Because Object is the root of the Dart class hierarchy, every other Dart class is a subclass of Object." in https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Object-class.html. 
What will happened if we will not extends Object? Or maybe it will be useful in some specific problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All dart classes implicitly extend `Object`, even if not specified.

This can be verified using the following code:

```dart
class Foo {}

void main() {
  var foo = Foo();
  print(foo is Object); // true
}
```

Even `null` implements `Object`, which allows doing:

```dart
null.toString()
null.hashCode
null == something
```

Comment: okay, so if it doesn't matter,  why he extends in almost all model classes?https://github.com/boeledi/flutter_crush/blob/master/lib/model/objective.dart

Comment: Raise an issue on that repository. I can't answer for him