# Flutter fill in a List based on data contained in other two lists

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have three list models as follow (oversimplified):

```
class Product extends Object {
  int? type;
  Product({type});
  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type= json["type"];
  }
}

class ProductWithPrice extends Object {
  int? type;
  double? price;
  ProductWithPrice ({type, price});
  ProductWithPrice.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type= json["type"];
    price= json["price"];
  }
}

class Prices extends Object {
  int? type;
  double? price;
  Prices ({type, price});
  Prices.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type= json["type"];
    price= json["price"];
  }
}
```

My lists are:

```
_productList<Product> = [{"type": orange}, {"type": apple}];
_productWithPriceList<ProductWithPrice> = []; //empty list
_pricesList<Prices> = [{"type": orange, "price": 100}, {"type": apple, "price": 200}];
```

Now, what I want to do is consisted of two phases:

1. Map and copy all `_productList` contents to the `_productWithPriceList`. I am not sure how to handle because of the additional `price` in the `ProductWithPrice` list model. Should the `price` be omitted or be set as `null`?
2. Once we have the `_productWithPriceList` populated, then we map and copy the `price` from `_pricesList` to the `_productWithPriceList` based on matching `type`.

Final output should be as follows:

```
_productWithPriceList<ProductWithPrice> = [{"type": orange, "price": 100}, {"type": apple, "price": 200}];
```

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: Btw, [All dart classes implicitly extend `Object`, even if not specified.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56935375/13625293)

Comment: Why do you have that odd json-like list?  Just use Map<Type, Price>.  And "Type" is a built-in, so you'll want to change that to ProductType or something.

Comment: I am using those list models across the entire app, getting JSON data via API and populating the lists like `list.map((model) =>Price.fromJson(model)).toList();`